# R - Populate column while some cells already have values

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following data set:

```
           Date Val1 Val2 Remarks
   1 2018-04-01  125 0.05  Closed
   2 2018-04-02    0 0.00
   3 2018-04-03  458 2.99  Closed
   4 2018-04-04    0 0.00  Closed
   5 2018-04-05  354 1.25
```

I want to automatically fill in the empty space in the Remarks column with "With Remittance" if Val1 > 0, and "Not yet" if Val1 = 0. The resulting dataset:

```
           Date Val1 Val2 Remarks
   1 2018-04-01  125 0.05  Closed
   2 2018-04-02    0 0.00  Not yet
   3 2018-04-03  458 2.99  Closed
   4 2018-04-04    0 0.00  Closed
   5 2018-04-05  354 1.25  With Remittance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward using `base` R:

```
data$Remarks[data$Val1 > 0 & is.na(data$Remarks)] <- "With Remittance"
data$Remarks[data$Val1 ==0 & is.na(data$Remarks)] <- "Not yet"
```

With using `tidyverse`:

```
data %>% 
mutate(Remarks_new = if_else(is.na(Remarks) & Val1 > 0, "With Remittance",
                     if_else(is.na(Remarks) & Val1 == 0, "Not yet", Remarks)))
```

Comment: Good Point! Feel free to modify so I can give you + pts for the correction.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer @akash87. I think there is an extra ) in the second line in the first set of codes

Comment: Good catch! sticky fingers I presume :-)

Comment: Can these codes be applied if the data in Val1 are string? Can I just replace 0 with a string value? @akash87

Comment: No because we are using a numeric operator. But if you are testing if a string is present vs not present then you can use `Val1 == "string"` or `Val1 != "string"`.

Comment: I encoutered this comment when I ran it with string: "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" @akash87

Comment: That means your data is not a data.frame or a tibble